# Use Python to put a track on a map

Tags: python, google-maps

I would like to show the track of a moving vehicle on a map in real time. The track information would be provide by an external GPS receiver, and I can convert NMEA sentences to KML or other text based formats.

I have previously created Python scripts to generate KML files (and others) for use with Google Earth and other map software but of course these are not real-time.

So far I have found many solutions for non-real-time display on Google Earth, but not real time. Also, real-time using web or cloud facilities, but my need is for an entirely local solution.

Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

An answer that worked for  me was to use Google Earth and load a position file using its  and  styles. Use this to refresh a KML file containing the position. Then when a new position is received, overwrite the KML file with the new position. Google Earth will then refresh the GE display. The position file can contain a series of coordinate statements and thus create a trail of recent positions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the Basemap package?  I would check that out over at http://matplotlib.org/basemap/ and also check out http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backgrounds.html to get a visual idea of what kind of maps/projections you will see.  The inputs to drawing on a Basemap image are Lat/Lon coordinations.

This may not be the answer you were looking for but it is something that can be done with Basemap.  I use Basemap to plot points on an image using Lat/Lon coordinates.

Comment: Belated thanks Noah. I had tried Basemap without much success, but I will get back to it.